# How to compile yacc/bison with multiple files?

Tags: parsing, compiler-errors, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I'd like to adjust the yacc-parser of the kconfig-libs (`/<path-to-kconfig>/libs/parser`). But I'm having problems for resolving various symbols, variables, functions, tokens, etc. I guess the problem is, that for the compiling not all files of the kconfig-parser are included. Here's what I do:

```
lex lconf.l
bison -d -y ./yconf.y 
gcc -o yconf y.tab.c
```

I get error messages like:

```
./yconf.y 499:44: Error: >>ROOTMENU<< not declared (first use in this function)
rootmenu.prompt = menu_add_prompt(P_MENU, ROOTMENU, NULL);
                                          ^

./yconf.y:576:2: Error: »zconfnerrs« not declared (first use in this function)
zconfnerrs++;
^

./yconf.y:546:3: Error: »zconfnerrs« not declared (first use in this function)
zconfnerrs++;
^
```

There are more files (.c and .h) in the directory of the parser, that (I guess) need to be included for the compiler-process: `hconf.c, lconf.c util.c symbol.c menu.c expr.c confdata.c, lkc.h lkc_proto.h` (but in the sourcecode there are already the specific `#include` commands)

I'm using this code straight out-of-the-box. When I use the makefile in  that directory it compiles without problems, but doing it manually like shown above doesn't seem to work. Unfortunately the makefile looks rather cryptic for me - since I'm not a makefile-pro - so it's not easy to look up what they did.

Thanks for advises, about where to "pass" these files, so that the compiling can be properly done.

Kind Regards

[**Edit**:]
The sources of the kconfiglib, can be found at http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/kconfig-frontends. The sources of the parser are located here: `/<path-to-kconfig>/libs/parser`

Comment: Would it be a lot to ask where you downloaded those files from, exactly? Not all of us have an encyclopedic knowledge of the entirety of the source repositories in the universe, and it would be helpful to see some more details.

Comment: Pardon me, I forgot about this. I added sources at the end of the top post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These build problems really have very little to do with bison or flex. Similar problems will occur any time you try to build a complex software project without using the project's build system.

So the simple answer is that the `kconfig-frontends` project is built using autotools, which means that you are expected to execute

```
./configure [options]
```

in the top-level directory in order to create the `Makefile`s needed to build the project.

As is usual, the git repository doesn't actually include the `configure` script. Rather, it is necessary to create that script (and other necessary configuration files) using autotools.

If you are using a release tarballs, you won't need to figure out how to generate the configure script, because it *is* included in the tarballs. So you will probably have fewer problems with the build.

As an aside, source management is not a simple problem and there are many contrasting opinions about how to do it. One of the problems is that it is quite common to inject modifications to the source files during the build process, for example in order to configure platform-specific defaults. For example, take the line:

```
rootmenu.prompt = menu_add_prompt(P_MENU, ROOTMENU, NULL);
```

found in the `conf_parse` function towards the bottom of `yconf.y`. Here, `ROOTMENU` is expected (I believe) to be a string containing the file path to the root menu; that file path will be installation-specific, so it is not defined anywhere in the source. Instead, it is injected in the `Makefile`, which will contain a line something like:

```
CPPFLAGS = -DROOTMENU="\"$(root_menu)\"" -DCONFIG_=\"$(config_prefix)\" ...
```

(It's more complicated than that; I'm simplifying the process considerably. But a line somewhat like that is in `libs/parser/Makefile.am` and you'll find something relevant in `libs/parser/Makefile` after you run `./configure` at the top level.)

`make` passes the `CPPFLAGS` -- that is, C PreProcessor flags -- to the C compiler when it needs to build an object file. (There are many such predefined variables; you can find a list in the documentation for `make`.) And `gcc` (and most other C compilers) interpret the `-DMACRO=value` to mean "predefine `MACRO` to `value` before preprocessing these source files".

The consequence is that you have macros whose definitions are not visible anywhere in the source files, unless you consider the input files for `automake` to be part of the source. Unless you know about these macros, you can't compile the files without using the bundled build system.

The above is a standard issue with C/C++ source distributions. The other problem you have could easily have been avoided (I think) but is also fairly common.

Both `flex` and `bison` come with an option to change the prefix `yy` in the generated code to something else. You need to do this if you have more than one parser or scanner in your project; otherwise there will be a clash of global symbols like `yylex` or (in this case) `yynerrs`. The `kconfig` project uses the prefix `zconf`, so the symbol `zconfnerrs` is the global variable which the parser increments each time it reports a syntax error. But for that to work, you need to set the prefix when you generate the parser with `bison` and the scanner with `flex`.

The prefix can be set in a command-line option, or it can be set in the `bison` and `flex` source files. As with the magic macros described above, using a command-line option makes the setting much less visible. Moreover, the generated code probably won't compile and certainly won't link if the prefixes are not set to the expected value. Consequently, I prefer to set the prefix in the source file, but not everyone shares this opinion, including, apparently, the author(s) of the package you're trying to build.

I found the settings in the top-level `configure` file:

```
AM_LFLAGS="-L -P zconf"
AM_YFLAGS="-t -l -p zconf"
```

These settings are used to create the `LFLAGS` (flex flags) and `YFLAGS` (bison "yacc" flags) variables for the Makefile. (They're easy to find if you know what you're looking for, but that's no excuse.)

For what it's worth, I would have put this setting into the source files:

```
  /* Flex (.l) file: */
%option prefix="zconf"

  /* Bison (.y) file: */
%define api.prefix "zconf"
```

The other command-line options are less critical, although they can also be set in the source file if desired.

I have no idea why the `-l/-L` flags are used: they cause bison/flex to omit the `#line` directives which link the generated files to the source line numbers in the `.y/.l` files; without these directives, debugging is more painful. The bison `-t` flag causes bison to include code for "tracing" the parse, although you still have to set the global variable `yydebug` (or `zconfdebug` in this case) to a non-zero value in order for the traces to actually be produced. Using `-t` is highly recommended because it costs little and simplifies debugging, but the project should build just fine without it.

Comment: Wow! that worked out fine. I didn't expect such a precise answer, that was very helpful I appreciate that much. Just for your interest: I **have** to use the -t option on the bison line in the makefile, else he wasn't able to resolve "zconfdebug". Besides, the information of your post made the bison/flex/yacc/lex world a bit clearer for me. Thank you for the support

Comment: @user3085931: If the project won't build without the `-t` flag to bison, then you might as well just include the directive `%debug` in the `yconf.y` file. That does the same thing, and doesn't require any support from the build system. (However, it won't work with `yacc` implementations other than `bison`, which is actually the same as the `%define api.prefix` line I suggested. I should edit the answer to mention that. Tomorrow.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there a difference between both methods? Isn't it the same, but just called at a different time ?

Comment: @user3085931: The only difference is that it makes the source file more self-contained. There's no "call"; the option is only used to generate the C file. (Setting `yydebug` is actually what causes the trace to happen; the `%debug` option inserts the test for `yydebug` into the C file.) In my opinion, a source file which *requires* a particular specific option setting should *include* that option, rather than having an undocumented dependency on the correct build command. However, evidently not everyone shares that opinion.

Comment: agreed to that opinion